# Control angular-flexslider from AngularJS control?

Tags: angularjs, flexslider

I am using [agular-flexslider](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-flexslider) and have the function `scrollTo` being called when a slide is selected:

```
<flex-slider slide="s in mySlides">
    <li>
        <img ng-src="{{s}}" ng-click="scrollTo($index)">
    </li>
</flex-slider>
```

I'd like to be able to call `scrollTo` from other methods in my controller to automatically move to the desired slide.  Any hints as to how to do this?  I am somewhat new to AngularJS.

Thanks in advance.